# How do I fix a package dependency error?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I can't install anything due to this. I have already tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but it did nothing. Here's the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsigsegv2 linux-headers-5.13.0-27-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-27
  linux-image-5.13.0-27-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-27-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-27-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libssl0.9.8
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl0.9.8
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 162 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/692 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,445 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 220950 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl0.9.8:amd64 (0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.0.9.8.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-7ubuntu3.2.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Do you know what you did to your system to cause this? It is likely from adding a ppa.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What version of Ubuntu are you using? What other commands did you run before `sudo apt-get install -f`? Did you remember that you have to run `sudo apt update` before doing anything else in `apt`? Did you run `sudo apt upgrade` for updates before attempting to install new software? You have 162 outdated packages. When's the last time you updated your system successfully?

Comment: @OrganicMarble i am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. i am new to linux so i really don't know how all this stuff works. i installed many packages to setup my pc. after some days an error message popped up stating " your installed packages have unmet dependencies" i don't know what package triggered the error though.

Comment: @Nmath i was trying to install some packages for setting up my pc ( i am a linux newbie btw ) . i am using  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS . i am sorry but i am still a newbie so i forgot to use the upgrade function. i just tried it now but it's showing an error. oh and btw i have a bad habit of pulling the plug instead of shutting down my pc. maybe that has something to do with this.

Comment: *"btw i have a bad habit of pulling the plug"* - This won't just destroy your operating system, it can brick your hardware. Don't *ever* do this... Reinstall the OS.  Your system probably has numerous issues from this behavior.  Remember to keep your system up-to-date and shut the system down properly when you turn it off.

Comment: @Nmath  sorry for  replying  late so i just reinstalled it like you said and  tried not to install any unwanted packages. i used to have so many packages earlier that i didn't even bother to update . i am so lucky that i had a second pc with me. my system was almost useless ( i couldn't even install a software for creating a boot up media)